# kube-system ingress pod is going to crashloopbackoff during openstack-helm installation

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install openstack-helm on a bare-metal. While installing ingress pods, the ingress pod with openstack namespace is coming up successfully but the ingress pod of kube-system namespace is going to crashloopbackoff. The following are the list of pods

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                             READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE       IP                NODE
kube-system   calico-etcd-lbxpt                                1/1       Running            0          3d        172.17.0.1
kube-system   calico-kube-policy-controllers-64b8674d9-dwq8k   1/1       Running            0          3d        172.17.0.1
kube-system   calico-node-sfq89                                2/2       Running            0          3d        172.17.0.1
kube-system   etcd-megam-1                                     1/1       Running            0          3d        172.17.0.1
kube-system   ingress-error-pages-6bfc8d875-tmqvd              1/1       Running            0          3d        192.168.232.131
**kube-system   ingress-rbv77                                    0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   1117**       3d        172.17.0.1
kube-system   kube-apiserver-megam-1                           1/1       Running            0          3d        172.17.0.1
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-megam-1                  1/1       Running            0          3d        172.17.0.1
kube-system   kube-dns-85648cfc65-pq44v                        3/3       Running            0          3d        192.168.232.129
kube-system   kube-proxy-n9zts                                 1/1       Running            0          3d        172.17.0.1
kube-system   kube-scheduler-megam-1                           1/1       Running            0          3d        172.17.0.1
kube-system   tiller-deploy-5c9c77f7c-bclsk                    1/1       Running            0          3d        192.168.232.130
openstack     ingress-c7f9b544c-984wk                          1/1       Running            0          3d        192.168.232.132
openstack     ingress-error-pages-57957f47f-25dgr              1/1       Running            0          3d        192.168.232.133
```

Even the nova pods are not coming up. Can anyone help how to fix this?

Comment: check the output of `kubectl logs -n kube-system ingress-rbv77`

Comment: Also if you can `kubectl describe pod ingress-rbv77 -n kube-system`

Comment: Thank you guys for the response. I checked the logs and found that port 80 was occupied by apache2 server in my baremetal. I stopped it now and it worked fine. :)